# Mixing C++ and C code - Linker issues in VS10

Tags: c, c++-cli

I've got a problem mixing the C++ and C code. My C++ code was created in VS10, i.e is a Windows Form project. I want include my C function in my C++ function through of linker (.obj). The steps are:

- Windows Form project

  - VS10 default project
  - Call the C function
  - Build the project manually using msbuild
- C code

  - Build the project manually through a make file using nmake and generates the objects files (.obj)

With the every objects files in hands (Cpp and C), the objects are linked in a third makefile. It's a simple idea but it doesn't work. The build in msbuild show the following message:

> error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A00000C) "extern "C" void __clrcall MinhaFuncao(void)" (?MinhaFuncao@@$$J0YMXXZ) referenced in function "int __clrcall main(cli::array^)" (?main@@$$HYMHP$01AP$AAVString@System@@@Z)
>
> error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "extern "C" void __clrcall MinhaFuncao(void)" (?MinhaFuncao@@$$J0YMXXZ) referenced in function "int __clrcall main(cli::array^)" (?main@@$$HYMHP$01AP$AAVString@System@@@Z)

The Cpp code:

```
    #include "stdafx.h"
#include "Form1.h"
//#include"complex.h"
extern "C" {
#include "complex.h"
}

/*extern "C" {
void MinhaFuncao();
}*/
extern "C" void MinhaFuncao();

using namespace WFormTesting;

[STAThreadAttribute]
int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    // Enabling Windows XP visual effects before any controls are created
    Application::EnableVisualStyles();
    Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false); 

    MinhaFuncao(); //<--- Calling the Function HERE -->

    // Create the main window and run it
    Application::Run(gcnew Form1());
    return 0;
}
```

The C code:

```
#include "complex.h"


void MinhaFuncao()
{
    printf("My function AOWWW.\n");
}
```

The header file:

```
#ifndef COMPLEX_H_
#define COMPLEX_H_

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
{
#endif

#include <stdio.h>

void MinhaFuncao();



#ifdef __cplusplus
} // extern "C"
#endif
#endif
```

Has someone got an idea about this problem? I read others posts about linker issues, but the solutions proposed don't work for me. I believe that the difference is due to the msbuild and the VS project... :/

Comment: So, are you compiling your C code as C code? I.e. is your compiler working in C mode when compiling your C code? In any case, `extern "C" {` around `#include "complex.h"` is excessive: everything that needs to be done is already done inside `complex.h`.

Comment: And this is not C++. This is C++-CLI apparently. Meanwhile, your question talks about C++. What is the task then: call C function from C++CLI or call C function from C++?

Comment: notice the `__clrcall` in the error message, you need to make sure your function declarations aren't in a managed section

Comment: @AnT  are you compiling your C code as C code? I don't certain about that, I believe that my C code was compiled as C++. "C++-CLI ": I don't know CLI, I checked the wikipedia now about that, and it isn't my idea use it.

Comment: @Fernando: Um... Yes,  I usually compile my C code as C code. Why?

Comment: @AlanBirtles "notice the __clrcall in the error message..." The manage sections are delimited by?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/cpp/preprocessor/managed-unmanaged

Comment: @AlanBirtles I checked the reference and change my code to put my function in unmanaged section, but it didn't promote a difference in the final result. The errors messages remain as early showed. #pragma managed(push, off)
extern "C" void MinhaFuncao();
#pragma managed(pop)

Comment: Which CLR mode are you using? I can only reproduce this problem in "/clr:safe" mode which doesn't support calling unmanaged functions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2012/ms173252(v=vs.110)

Comment: @AlanBirtles I'm using the "Default image type", but I change it for testing and the error remains when I use the "Force Pure IL Image" which probably is the default. When I use the "Safe" or "IJW" the following message is showed: "fatal error LNK1309: pure module detected; invalid with switch /CLRIMAGETYPE:SAFE". It's due to my pragma instructions inserted in the code.

Comment: I mean the setting in "Configuration\properties\General\Common Language runtime support", I think you shouldn't need to fiddle with the linker setting

Comment: I'm using the "Pure MSIL...", with the "safe" many others issues are shown. I don't know the reason for my link doesn't work fine. I only need access a C function through an Event generated from Windows Form. However, appear for me that traditional method for mixing doesn't work in an easy way with CLI.

Comment: Try changing to "/clr" mode, should work

Comment: @AlanBirtles The error remains... :(

Comment: Ideally `extern "C"` would be enough to fix this, but that is not the way compiler writers think.  It suppresses C++ name mangling, it doesn't do anything to the calling convention.  Find the #include back in your source code.  Before it write `#pragma managed(push, off)`, after it write `#pragma managed(pop)`.  Now the C++/CLI compiler knows that the .h file does not declare managed functions.  Might not solve the linker error, although it should now change to `__cdecl`, helps you to focus on linking the correct library.

Answer (score 0):

You are using extern "C"  in an extern C block

remove the outer extern C block surrounding
`#include "complex.h"`

Comment: I did it, but the error remains. I believe if my code both were manuals (outside VS10), my approach would work fine. However, the mixing inside the VS10 probably has some particularity outside my skills about that.